# Recommendation for backpacking trip in April

Tags: weather-and-climate, recommendations

I am considering a backpacking trip in April for about a month. I am looking for a destination that:

- Is "exotic" for an European (so I rule out the whole of Europe, USA, Canada, Australia and New Zeland)
- April is a reasonable month to visit (I am thinking mainly about climate)
- Is malaria-free
- Is reasonably safe (e.g. I wouldn't consider Syria at the moment)
- Has either rich cultural heritage or natural beauty. I am after "world class", breath-taking monuments (so for instance I wouldn't consider Armenia - ignoring the fact that its in Europe - even though it has a couple of really nice monasteries)

I am flying from London with my family. Budget is a secondary issue.

I would be grateful for all recommendations.